# Is there no way to secure rancher before first run?

Tags: rancher

I've been looking for a way to setup github OAuth2 access from some config or cmd line, or even how to setup a basic password auth until that can be established from the UI.

https://github.com/rancher/rancher

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for a basic account type:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "http://Your_rancher_url:PORT/v1/localauthconfig" -d '{"enabled": "true", "username":"NewUsersName", "password": "NewUsersPassword" }'
```

You can setup OAuth2 too, check here:
http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.1/en/api/v1/access-control/